# How to take screenshot on failure

Tags: javascript, screenshot, playwright

Is there an easy way to tell Playwright (JS) to take screenshots on test failure?

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-use-options#recording-options?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting Playwright Docs [about screenshots](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-screenshot)

```js
// playwright.config.js file
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  use: {
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure',
  },
});
```

Screenshot setting modes are `"off"|"on"|"only-on-failure"`
in your case `only-on-failure` is what you're looking for.